# 8th Honda civic engine rotations surges

Tags: engine, honda, civic, sparkplugs, idle

Due to bad gasoline on the highway the spark plugs are worn. There was an evacuation of the car and then it got to the mechanic. Old spark plugs (iridium) were replaced with new (iridium too), after which the engine worked for some time on the cleaning fluid instead of gasoline (mechanic turned off the suction from the gas tank). After that the throttle has been cleared and the battery terminal was reset.

Then significant engine rotations surges immediately began, especially in idle state. There was an idea that it's something about the throttle adaptation, but I've already ridden more than 5 thousand kilometers. Maybe the problem is in idle air control actuator? Any advice and explanation would be appreciated.

P.S. The mileage of the car is about 150000 km. Errors are not displayed.

P.P.S Immediately after starting the engine and some time after that, the engine works quite loudly (there is "murmuring" noise on *Parking*, *Shift*, *Reverse*, not on *Neutral*). If immediately after starting the engine to switch to the *Reverse*, the murmuring noise becomes scary loud.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of ***engine rotations surges*** is that the throttle adaptation was not reset correctly after cleanup. So after the appropriate manipulations with the *PGM-FI* everything is fine.

The reason of the ***engine loud working*** and vibrations (especially on *Reverse*) is that the engine support was busted. Hence there were some vibrations on cold engine.

Answer (score 1):

If you said that the problem begans when you were driving with bad fuel, probably is a clogged fuel filter, of course if the mechanic didn't changes it, if it isn't that it could be a clogged inyector because cleannig fluid cleans up all the fuel lines include those who are after the fuel filter, and I wish you add more information about the noise, what kind of noise, is it clunk or like a clicking noise, hope it fix your problem, oh, and about the idle air control actuator, I think that car doesn't even have one, because it is an electric throttle, and that type of throttle controls its idle with the throttle plate.

Comment: Thank you for your attention! I edited my question about noise. I have a video with it (it's about 90Mb). How can I show you?